# depth relation search

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

I am looking for a "pythonic" / "orm-ic" solution for this problem...

Model `Soldier` has a ManyToManyField to itself.

```
class Soldier(models.Model):
    ...
    subordinates = models.ManyToManyField('Soldier', ...)
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are `Soldier` objects

They form kind of "chain of command" like so: A > B > C

`B` is in `A.subordinates.all()`
`C` is in `B.subordinates.all()`

What's the best way to get all subordinates of `A`?
Something like `A.get_all_subordinates()`, that should return `[B, C]`.

We don't know how many levels of this relation there is at runtime. (`C` can have some subordinates of his own, `B` can have siblings, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you model the superior <-> subordinate relation with a many-to-many relation, you'll end up with a graph-like structure that can get arbitrary complex (e.g. circular relations). This will become very hard to query efficiently.

If you're after a tree-like structure (which means that every `Soldier` has at most one direct superior), you could use [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/):

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel

class Soldier(MPTTModel):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Getting all the subordinates is then as easy as

```
subordinates = soldier.get_descendants()
```

And the best thing about `get_descendants`: it causes exactly one query to get all descendants.